# Auto proxy detection is not working properly in wireless network for Windows 7 machines

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

Cisco/AIR-WLC4404-100-K9, Auto proxy detection is not working properly in wireless network for Windows 7 machines.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Is the proxy on the same network as the wireless devices attempting to use it?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd672673(WS.10).aspx